# Function to clear UserForms checkbox in VBA

Tags: vba, checkbox, userform

I am creating a program which has several UserForms.
At the end of the program I need to clear every Checkbox inside some UserForm. I have created a Function, but it cannot recognise which UserForm it should clear, can you help me there? Here is the code:

```
Function ClearUserForm(ByVal userf As String)

Dim contr As Control

For Each contr In userf.Controls

    If TypeName(contr) = "CheckBox" Then
        contr.Value = False
    End If
Next

End Function
```

And I am calling the function like this, for example:

```
ClearUserForm ("UserForm2")
```

It seems not to recognize which UserForm it should act upon.

Comment: try the code below and let me know if it works like you intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `Function` (since you are not returning any arguments), in your case a `Sub` will do.

You need to qualify an Object to the `User_Form` selected by using:

```
Set objUserForm = UserForms.Add(userf)
```

### Whole code

(Tested)

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearUserForm(ByVal userf As String)

Dim contr As Control
Dim objUserForm As Object

Set objUserForm = UserForms.Add(userf)

For Each contr In objUserForm.Controls

    If TypeName(contr) = "CheckBox" Then
        contr.Value = False
    End If
Next
' just to check that all checkboxes are cleared
objUserForm.Show

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Shai Rado's advice is good and you should have a look at how he creates the object from its 'key'.

I only post this answer to check if you're aware that you could pass the object itself in the call. So your code could be like so:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RunMe()
    ClearCBoxes UserForm1
End Sub

Private Sub ClearCBoxes(frm As MSForms.UserForm)
    Dim ctrl As Control

    For Each ctrl In frm.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.ComboBox Then
            ctrl.Value = False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: LOL :) my ego is too big anyway, I won't even feel it ;) . But you also added a nice thing with passing the `Object` +1